# Stop method from execution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this color changer method which changes the color of my sprites continuously. My problem is that I want to pause it when I execute the OnMouseDown() Method.

I have tried it with a if and return statement. I as well tried it with a Boolean but it doesn't work.

```
       public class colorchange : MonoBehaviour
       {
        public int color;

private SpriteRenderer _mySpriteRenderer;
private float _timeBetweenChanges = 1f;

void Start()
{
    _mySpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    InvokeRepeating("ChangeColor", 0F, _timeBetweenChanges);
}

void Update()
{
    // not executed
}

void ChangeColor()
{
        color = Random.Range(1, 5);
        if (color == 2)
        {
            _mySpriteRenderer.color = Color.blue;
        }
        if (color == 3)
        {
            _mySpriteRenderer.color = Color.red;
        }
        if (color == 4)
        {
            _mySpriteRenderer.color = Color.yellow;
        }




}
private void OnMouseDown()
{
  // the Changecolor method should be paused in this one
}
}
```

Comment: I have never programmed in Unity, but did a quick google search and think that [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html) documentation page has your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to [`CancelInvoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html) as mentioned in the comments is to use a bool.

```
public class colorchange : MonoBehaviour {

private bool canChangeColor;

//...

private void ChangeColor() {
   if (!canChangeColor) {
       // You can even do something here if you like.
       return;
   }
   // ...
}

private void OnMouseDown(){
   canChangeColor = false;
}
}
```

Though I would highly suggest using `CancelInvoke` instead, unless you need it to do something if it can't change color.

Comment: @LaurenzKaml How did it not work, can you include some error log? Also, the game object needs to have a Collider in order for `OnMouseDown` to work. (I am not so sure if rigidbody is needed too.)

Comment: @LaurenzKaml Do you even know if your `OnMouseDown()` method is called? If you put `Debug.Log("Test123");` inside `OnMouseDown()`, does anything get printed?

Comment: @LaurenzKaml "It doesn't work" is not informative.  Tell us what its actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, `CancelInvoke` and a `boolean flag` are options.

However, I prefer/ suggest a different approach.

Change your method into a couroutine.

```
public class colorchange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int color;

    private SpriteRenderer _mySpriteRenderer;
    private float _timeBetweenChanges = 1f;
    private Coroutine _colorRoutine;

    void Start()
    {
        _mySpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        _colorRoutine = StartCoroutine(ChangeColor());
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeColor()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            color = Random.Range(1, 5);
            if (color == 2)
            {
                _mySpriteRenderer.color = Color.blue;
            }
            else if (color == 3)
            {
                _mySpriteRenderer.color = Color.red;
            }
            else if (color == 4)
            {
                _mySpriteRenderer.color = Color.yellow;
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_timeBetweenChanges);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        StopCoroutine(_colorRoutine );
    }
}
```

I prefer this approach since you can keep a reference to the routine and you could even change the delay time without stopping/ starting.

Also, you are not dependent on a string matching the method name and can pass in additinoal parameters when using a Coroutine as opposed to an Invoke method.

Comment: I suspect that something else is not working in your code, seeing as you said the same about Kaynn's answer and his answer should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is starting to seem like you don't actually want to use `OnMouseDown` because you can't or won't attach a collider to the object being clicked, or you want the mouse click to be detected anywhere. That being the case, I recommend using `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` to detect a mouse click occurring anywhere. I also recommend using a coroutine to make use of convenient tools like `WaitUntil`:

```
public class colorchange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int color;        
    public float delaySeconds = 1f;
    IEnumerator changeColorCoroutine;

    SpriteRenderer mySprite;

    public bool doChangeColor;

    void Start()
    {
        // cache result of expensive GetComponent call
        mySprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        // initialize flag
        doChangeColor = true;

        // create coroutine
        changeColorCoroutine = ChangeColor();

        // start coroutine
        StartCoroutine(changeColorCoroutine);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // toggle doChangeColor
            doChangeColor = !doChangeColor;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeColor()
    {
        WaitUntil waitForFlag = new WaitUntil( () => doChangeColor);

        while (true)
        {
            yield return waitForFlag;

            Debug.Log("Hello");
            color = Random.Range(1, 5);

            // switch for neater code
            switch (color)
            {
            case 2:
                mySprite.color = Color.blue;
                break;

            case 3:
                mySprite.color = Color.red;
                break;

            case 4:
                mySprite.color = Color.yellow;
                break;
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delaySeconds);
        }
    }
}
```